# Error TS2322: Type 'Object[]' is not assignable to type '[Object]'

Tags: typescript, ecmascript-6, typescript-typings, definitelytyped

I have a code snippet like this:

```
export class TagCloud {

    tags: [Tag];
    locations: [Location];

    constructor() {
        this.tags = new Array<Tag>();
        this.locations = new Array<Location>();
    }
}
```

But this gives me the following errors:

> error TS2322: Type 'Tag[]' is not assignable to type '[Tag]'.
>     Property '0' is missing in type 'Tag[]'.
>
> error TS2322: Type 'Location[]' is not assignable to type '[Lo
>   cation]'.
>     Property '0' is missing in type 'Location[]'.

What am I doing wrong (the code is working though)?

I am using typings with the es6-shim Type descriptions (https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/tree/master/es6-shim).

Answer (score 33, accepted):

In typescript when you declare an array you either do:

```
let a: Array<number>;
```

or

```
let a: number[];
```

When you use:

```
let a: [number];
```

you are in fact declaring [a tuple](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html#tuple), in this case of length one with number.
This is another tuple:

```
let a: [number, string, string];
```

The reason you get this error is because the length of the array you assign to `tags` and `locations` are 0, and it should be 1.

Answer (score 2):

You want to use `Tag[]` to tell TypeScript you are declaring an array of `Tag`.

```
export class TagCloud {

    tags: Tag[];
    locations: Location[];

    constructor() {
        // TS already knows the type
        this.tags = []
        this.locations =[]
    }
}
```